# Get product image cache path sql

Tags: product-images, cache, sql

I need to get product image path with raw sql. Where does Magento store product image cache path? Table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` stores images but without the cache path (`/2/0/20.jpg`).

Comment: let me know the magento version please

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$thumbnailpath = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
$bigImagepath = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
$smallImagepath = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image');
```

Check also this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1008/7781

Comment: I can not use Magento models, I need raw sql.

Comment: You have no way to do that. Because the path is constructed "dinamically" Read this, please: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1008

Answer (score 0):

The URL of images in cache is complex because it contains the MD5 of image params.(example: 
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/e/me-d1_2.jpg)

But you can easily get the original image URL.

To get the base URL (unsecure):

```
SELECT value FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url'
```

If you want the secure URL:

```
SELECT value FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/secure/base_url'
```

it returns the website URL.

To construct the image URL, add "media/catalog/product" and the image path (example: "/a/c/ace-furniture.jpg").

Example:

```
http://example.com/media/catalog/product/a/c/ace-furniture.jpg
```