# Have any way to get product gallery image full path from image name in magento2?

Tags: magento2, image

I have product gallery image  **/d/i/digitalnumber_0209_text.jpg**

Using this image i want 
**http://www.stm2local.com/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\5774940f9400924b0454113a9911cfd5/d/i/digitalnumber_0209_text.jpg**

Have any idea about misc params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be want to know about `cache\5774940f9400924b0454113a9911cfd5` of

`http://www.stm2local.com/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\5774940f9400924b0454113a9911cfd5/d/i/digitalnumber_0209_text.jpg`

Magento create cache copied of image  `/d/i/digitalnumber_0209_text.jpg` image from the location

`magentodire/pub/media/catalog/product/d/i/digitalnumber_0209_text.jpg`

to

`magentodire/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/5774940f9400924b0454113a9911cfd5//d/i/digitalnumber_0209_text.jpg`

when resizing or other purposes. As a store owner, you don't lose the main during resize or other operation. So you have  to create cache image.

IN cache path, `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` statically define  and where  `5774940f9400924b0454113a9911cfd5` is dynamically define by  form
`Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\Image`

```
 private function getMiscPath()
    {
        return $this->encryptor->hash(implode('_', $this->miscParams), Encryptor::HASH_VERSION_MD5);
    }
```

Add good description about Magento 1 cache, available at [Get original image file from a cache URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/get-original-image-file-from-a-cache-url)

If you will look on  `getAbsolutePath` and `getRelativePath`  method of `Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\Image`

and `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image` then you understand how magento create cache copy of original image.